# Which certificate and key does Kubernetes use to sign CertificateSigningRequests?

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubectl, x509

I was trying to automate the process of signing Kubernetes certificates for new users.
The official documentation ([here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#normal-user)) suggests using Kubectl. In particular they suggest using the command :

`kubectl certificate approve csr_name`

and obtain a base64 encoded certificate via :

`kubectl get csr/csr_name -o yaml`

and looking at the `status.certificate` field. Since I have access to the cluster certificates ( at /etc/kubernetes/pki) and since I wanted to further automate the process I was wondering which certificate and key are used by Kubernetes in the signing process. I've tried with apiserver, ca and kubeadmin (.crt and .key) and openssl as follows :

`openssl x509 -req my.csr -days 365 -CA /etc/kubernetes/*.crt -CAkey /etc/kubernetes/*.key -CAcreateserial -out my.crt`

where `*.crt` and `*.key` are the various files mentioned above. But the results are always different from that of the kubectl command. Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very partial answer for this moment

**1.** **CA for etcd, kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kubelet, and kube-proxy**

> Since I have access to the cluster certificates ( at
> /etc/kubernetes/pki) and since I wanted to further automate the
> process I was wondering which certificate and key are used by
> Kubernetes in the signing process.

There is a great [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) tutotial that give you great opportunity to check,test and try by your own how to manually create kubernetes cluster using manually create all the certificates for core resources.

[Provisioning a CA and Generating TLS Certificates](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md)

> you will provision a PKI Infrastructure using CloudFlare's PKI
> toolkit, cfssl, then use it to bootstrap a Certificate Authority, and
> generate TLS certificates for the following components: etcd,
> kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kubelet, and
> kube-proxy.

[Generating Kubernetes Configuration Files for Authentication](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/05-kubernetes-configuration-files.md#generating-kubernetes-configuration-files-for-authentication)

> you will generate Kubernetes configuration files, also known as
> kubeconfigs, which enable Kubernetes clients to locate and
> authenticate to the Kubernetes API Servers.

**2.** **New user creation**
you can use [Kubernetes: How do I access the CA to sign a new user certificate?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/kubernetes-how-do-i-access-the-ca-to-sign-a-new-user-certificate) as a reference. Copy pasting for history in case original post would be removed

> you can use the build in CA in your cluster to create client
> certificates. Background information on how to use the CA:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/

Assuming you have a user.json

```
{
    "CN": "mfrank",
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 4096
    },
    "names": [{
        "O": "mfrank",
        "email": "some@email"
    }]
}
```

> You can then generate a CSR for this. In this example I use cfssl to
> generate the CSR:

```
cfssl genkey user.json  | cfssljson -bare client
```

> You can now use kubectl to submit a CSR for your cluster:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: mfrank
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  - mfrank
  request: $(cat client.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
EOF
```

> The request field is base64 encoded version of your csr file.
>
> To view your CSR: kubectl get csr
>
> To approve it:

```
kubectl certificate approve mfrank
```

> Decode it:

```
kubectl get csr mfrank -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d > client.pem
```

> You can now use the client-key.pem and client.pem to build a
> kubeconfig.
>
> You can then create RBAC rolebindings on your cluster assigning to
> either –user=mfrank or –group=mfrank (assuming you used “O”: “mfrank”)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to give such a nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a CSR, you must specify a *signer*, i.e., a controller loop run within the kube-controller-manager. The signer will sign the CSR and update the `status` field with the generated certificate.

For example, to request a client certificate to authenticate against the kube-apiserver, you need to use the `kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client` signer. By default, the cluster's CA private key (usually located at `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key`) is used.

(You can set your own by passing the `--cluster-signing-kube-apiserver-client-key-file` flag to the kube-controller-manager binary; this flag will set the private key file used to populate the `KubeAPIServerClientSignerConfiguration.KeyFile` and sign CSRs.)

The following manifest creates a CSR for a new `john` user:

```yaml
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: john
spec:
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  usages: ["digital signature", "key encipherment", "client auth"]
  request: |
    LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURSBSRVFVRVNULS0tLS0KTUlJQ1ZEQ0NBVHdDQVFBd0R6RU5N
    QXNHQTFVRUF3d0VhbTlvYmpDQ0FTSXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRApnZ0VQQURDQ0FRb0Nn
    Z0VCQUxLWnVjbHlLYUpqVzM0aUdRSEptazllUjc5VkRVdVVqbTNEYjNtUU9QaTVLSjlkCklsTloy
    b3l2YmdJVDBGcXF3amgyaWgvL1h5RnYyUU43OWM0TW1MUTBsSFZ2T0V1bDBaZFpBSGNUVk5yZWt4
    SHgKOVVtSlBtb3Bwbm5yYjhuYS90NnpMc0xMbkE0NHZteEZyay9kYlN3V2t2aE1sSktVOStSbUdN
    NEJGOEw0NzR1VQp4MERvSDIwaXEzNDNmTUVCeEc0N3hpQzVLbXFIdFlUeG9JOXBjMzlJTTVtTE8w
    YXlzSHJHTjFQbXpzVGpVMU1DCkNhNzZKSVhGRFZHckFlUFk1eS96R2NPdzZjYkVFZDhpMGlPNDJy
    T3RFK1hER1puNk13N1JGWTkxMDgxMVhaZEUKd3RqY1F5Z05TdDcvOFpIU3J3TCtXditmbFhlYmRV
    V2EyQVVMTllFQ0F3RUFBYUFBTUEwR0NTcUdTSWIzRFFFQgpDd1VBQTRJQkFRQllGbVBHSmRpcGtx
    a0tPRlJxWjRXM09ESmlLaEF5K1NkVDZMNTFhSnVuenNWKzVTMXlaUFhjCndSeUdLRkdGWHd3YVdh
    UGllQVZuSkUvUHdzQ0d2RlhJSDl0dmcwZ1hrZjNxWG96dTc3N29PNC9aU21aOUxwOGYKTE13R3Vs
    dWVLVjhMalhRZWtkQXdtMmQzaUJOMGxVbllNK2FNVTlhWC8xeEl4aG02ZWNjRXJKa0txdCtZbGt6
    YQpROHhTWlBsamMydXhCbllrMFdPUjZOdmpYNW9Zell4WVU4UWdLQjgyNnBhdFl4OTZuZG14Vy8r
    bkpPSkJNaUNOCnpsSUJzNzhOdWgrZlFmOGlnSjZwUFNub1RaNlFRa3R4czk5NFEzV09ONkRtSFli
    THN1V21zNCsrTHZFWFZUeTQKbjJTN3owQ3NsOVdlT3o5QytsaXEvcy9XRDl5dEZESmsKLS0tLS1F
    TkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUgUkVRVUVTVC0tLS0tCg==
```

Once applied, you can approve the CSR and display the generated certificate:

```bash
$ kubectl certificate approve john
$ kubectl get csr john -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

(You can see the username by looking for the Common Name (CN) field.)